# Google Analytics Api 400 Bad Request

Tags: c#, google-api, google-analytics-api, http-status-code-400

I want to import data from Google Analytics.

```
var gas = new AnalyticsService(auth);

var r = gas.Data.Ga.Get("ga:6332XXXX", "2013-02-01", "2013-02-11", "ga:visits");

r.Dimensions = "ga:date";
r.Sort = "ga:visits";
r.StartIndex = 1;

var data = r.Fetch();
```

I get 400 bad request error in Fetch method. What is the wrong of my code?

My full code like following:

```
var scope = AnalyticsService.Scopes.AnalyticsReadonly.ToString();
var clientId = "--------.apps.googleusercontent.com";
var keyFile = @"C:\-----------------privatekey.p12";
var keyPassword = "notasecret";

var desc = GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description;

var key = new X509Certificate2(keyFile, keyPassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

var client = new AssertionFlowClient(desc, key)
{
    ServiceAccountId = clientId,
    Scope = scope
};

var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator<AssertionFlowClient>(client, AssertionFlowClient.GetState);

var gas = new AnalyticsService(auth);

var r = gas.Data.Ga.Get("ga:6332XXXX", "2013-02-01", "2013-02-11", "ga:visits");

r.Dimensions = "ga:date";
r.Sort = "ga:visits";
r.StartIndex = 1;

var data = r.Fetch();
```

Thaks for your interest.

Comment: First try out your query with google analytics api explorer http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ideas:

1. your clientId should be your SERVICE ACCOUNT EMAIL (not id)
2. your scope should be "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly"

If this doesn't work, check [@Martyn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17016863/3661)